# SpeechSynthesisUtterance not working in lightning controller

Tags: lightning

I have this code :

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
console.log(msg);
```

it displays this error... upon initialization

> [Failed to construct 'SpeechSynthesisUtterance': Please use the 'new'
>   operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

I tried doing **new SpeechSynthesisUtterance**, removed new , tried window.Speechsynthesis... etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok and it is working fine in Visual Force Page. But it is not working in lightning.

We can test **speechSynthesis** is supported or not using below code. This feature was disabled by locker service.

```
    if('speechSynthesis' in window)
    {
        var speech = new window.SpeechSynthesisUtterance('hello baby');
        speech.lang = 'en-US';
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('speechSynthesis not supported');
    }
```

After Disabling locker service of that component (**put api version to 39**) your code will work fine.

Comment: I did this and it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: worked for me in LWC component which was placed in Community site, Thanks!